# What is the difference between those two sentences?

Tags: meaning, word-order, syntactic-analysis

> 1 There is a room separate from my bedroom.
>
> 2 There is a separate room from my bedroom.

Is there a difference in meaning between those two sentences? Or are they the same?

Answer (score 2):

They are the same in terms of their meaning, though their emphasis may differ.

Consider the first: There is a room [which is] separate from my bedroom. 'Room' may be the emphasis, and the qualifier 'separate from my bedroom' becomes the tail, or the qualifier itself may be the emphasis as it isn't split. Of course, this only really is identifiable in speech.

In the second, the emphasis is almost certainly 'separate' or 'separate room'. You could almost see 'from my bedroom' as a secondary qualifier in this case.